# SQL Server : user-defined function that returns the sum of all the values corresponding to an employeeID

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use a scalar function that takes an `employeeID` in as a parameter and returns the total sales amount made by that employee.

Unfortunately, my code keeps returning the total but multiple times, once for each instance of `employeeID` in the table. How would I make my function return a single value?

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufnEmployeeRevenue (@employeeID INT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @total MONEY

    SELECT DISTINCT @total = SUM(S.Total)
    FROM tblSale S
    WHERE S.EmployeeID = @employeeID

    RETURN @total
END

SELECT dbo.ufnEmployeeRevenue(EmployeeID) 
FROM tblSale
WHERE EmployeeID = 1

[enter image description here][1]
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXkg.png)

Comment: Remove `from tblSale...` you need just to pass the ID number.

Comment: Are you referring to the from tbSale... in the second select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call is wrong, you just need to pass the `ID` number:

```
select dbo.ufnEmployeeRevenue(1);
```

When you pass `1` (or any id number) to the function, it will run the code inside it as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT @total = SUM(S.Total)
    FROM tblSale S
    WHERE S.EmployeeID = 1 --@employeeID
```

Finally, it will return the final result for you.

Details about `functions` can be found in the **[Create User-defined Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine)**, which include examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning that scalar function into an inline table valued function instead. It is faster than a scalar function and far more flexible. Here is the same logic as an inline table valued function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ufnEmployeeRevenue (@employeeID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
    SELECT TotalMoney = SUM(S.Total)
    FROM tblSale S
    WHERE S.EmployeeID = @employeeID

GO

SELECT m.TotalMoney
FROM tblSale s
cross apply dbo.ufnEmployeeRevenue(EmployeeID) m
WHERE EmployeeID = 1
```